# Improper display of spanish word "término" in browser

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Spanish word  "término"  gets displayed on browser as `t&#233;rmino.`
I have resource file to store this word.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString("t&#233;rmino")
```

Comment: In Resource file I have term like término but on browser it's gettinf diaplayed as `t&#233;rmino`

Answer (score 0):

I think that your text is already encoded and razor is trying to encode it again as by default it encodes all outputs

Try doing something like

```
@Html.Raw(MyResources.Strings_Resources.SpanishText)
```

SpanishText here will be the value you are try to print (City/ Description or whatever the name of that string is)